# How does one do 2-way communication with async javascript generators?

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming, generator

The ability to do 2-way communication with js generators is super powerful (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/next#Sending_values_to_the_generator)). It enables something similar to channels in programming languages based on CSP.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this with async generators though. Suppose I create an async generator in the following way:

```
async function* asyncGenFn() {
  yield Promise.resolve(true)
}
```

This function returns `AsyncIterableIterator` (not `AsyncIterator`), which doesn't seem to have a `next` function like `IterablIterator` does.

Is there a way to do 2-way communication with async generators created this way? Or am I just barking up the wrong tree here?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you elaborate, show some example code and the desired output? See [here](http://2ality.com/2016/10/asynchronous-iteration.html), `asyncIterator.next()` seems to be fine

Comment: sorry about that, updated!

Comment: I'm getting back an `AsyncGenerator` instance from calling your `asyncGenFn()` as expected. What is this `AsyncIterableIterator` you are talking about, what environment are you running this in?

Comment: It does allow to run `next()`, I wrote a small blog about async generators here... https://medium.com/@segersian/howto-async-generators-in-nodejs-c7f0851f9c02 , so the `next()` function is exposed, you just need to make sure to await.

Comment: Ok, I just realized this was an issue on my end; didn't include `esnext.asynciterable` in my typescript compiler options. Will add an answer saying so and close this out

Thanks all for taking a look!

Comment: You might want to edit in the exact Typescript warning that you got, so that future searchers with the same problem will be able to find this question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of 2-way communication using generators -

```js
const g = function* (x)
{ // yield sends a message "out"
  // inbound message will be assigned to msg1
  const msg1 = yield "sending this out"
  
  // another outbound message
  // inbound message will be assigned to msg2
  const msg2 = yield "sending this too" 
  
  // do something
  console.log(msg1, msg2)
  
  // finally, return a value
  // don't forget generators can accept arguments, like x here
  return x * 2
}

// instantiate the generator
const iterator = g (100)

// get the first value from the iterator
let val = iterator.next()

// some example message to send to the generator
let m = 1

while (!val.done)
{ // log each outbound message
  console.log("received message", val.value)
  
  // .next resumes the generator and sends a message back "in"
  val = iterator.next(m)
  
  // increment the example message
  m = m + 1
}

// display the final value
console.log("return value", val.value)
```

Output

```
received message sending this out
received message sending this too
1 2
return value 200
```

---

It might be better to learn about 2-way communication by applying it to a problem. This pause/resume behavior given to us by generators makes them great for handling asynchronous operations. The newer `async` and `await` allows us to blur the lines between synchronous and asynchronous code -

```js
const delay = x =>
  new Promise (r => setTimeout (r, 1e3, x))

const main = async (z) =>
{ const x = await delay (200) // some promise
  const y = await delay (300) // some promise
  return x + y + z            // some computation with all the values
}

main (100) .then (console.log, console.error)
// 2 seconds later...
// => 600
```

But before we had `async` and `await`, we had generators. One nice demonstration of 2-way communication with generators is `run` below. It allows us to write our program exactly the same, except using a generator function and a `yield` expression -

```js
const delay = x =>
  new Promise (r => setTimeout (r, 1e3, x))

const main = function* (z)
{ const x = yield delay (200) // some promise
  const y = yield delay (300) // some promise
  return x + y + z            // some computation with all the values
}

const run = it =>
{ const loop = ({ done, value }) =>
    done
      ? Promise .resolve (value)
      : value .then (x => loop (it .next (x)))
  return loop (it .next ())
}

run (main (100)) .then (console.log, console.error)
// 2 seconds later...
// => 600
```

Above, `run` is implemented as a simple recursive function that takes a generators outbound promise and sends the promise's resolved value back into the generator. It does this until the generator is exhausted and resolves the final value -

```
const run = it =>
{ const loop = ({ done, value }) =>

    // if the iterator is done
    done

      // resolve the final value
      ? Promise .resolve (value)

      // otherwise resolve the value, send it back into the generator, recur
      : value .then (x => loop (it .next (x)))

  // initialize the loop with the first value
  return loop (it .next ())
}
```

Before we could use generators to mock coroutines, we were stuck writing asynchronous programs by manually chaining `.then` calls around in our code -

```js
const delay = x =>
  new Promise (r => setTimeout (r, 1e3, x))

const main = z =>
  delay (200) .then (x => // manually chain then
  delay (300) .then (y => // manually chain then
  x + y + z               // some computation with all the values
  ))                      // close each then
  
main (100) .then (console.log, console.error)
// 2 seconds later...
// => 600
```

As you can see, 2-way communication with generators is powerful and affords us beautiful expression of complex programs. JavaScript adds `async`/`await` keywords that might make it seem like magic, but `run` gives you an idea of how you can use 2-way communication to get the same behaviour, even without the new keywords.

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue on my end having to do with Typescript compilation options. Adding the following to my `tsconfig.json` solved the problem for me:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "lib": ["esnext.asynciterable"]
}
```

Thanks everyone who took a look!